# OrientDB relationship betwen to classes results same row

Tags: orientdb, nosql

Im new working with OrientDB, I have two classes  extended of OGraphVertex and one class extended of OGraphEdge, when i execute the next query I recibe my Tag in a row and the child in other row, I want do an union of all of this for show in a report list (the same like use joins in MySQL), Some one can help me with this query?

traverse out from ( traverse out_tagsparent from (select * from Tags where @rid = #16:10) )

Regards

Comment: OGraphVertex and OGraphEdge are related to OrientDB 1.3, something like 2-3 years ago. Are you using a super old version?

Comment: hi @Lvca, I'm using 1.7.3 I downloaded around 15 days ago, Im new whit orientDB

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use graph functions ( `in()` and `out()` ) rather properties.

So in your query would look like

```
TRAVERSE out('tagsparent') FROM #16:10
```

And yes, make sure that you extending from V and E classes.

Comment: thank you @enisher this query give me the information in two rows and I wanna only one for show in a list, I wanna replicate this MySQL query. Select * From Tags a Inner Join Tags b On a.parent_tag = b.id, i really appreciate your help, regards

Comment: "this query give me the information in two rows and I wanna only one for show in a list"
What do you mean by this?